# How do I connect my Laravel 5 app to mysql using MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I've gotten several different errors running php artisan migrate while trying different things.  The most recent one is:

```
Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES
```

This is my database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    'port' => '3306'
],
```

and this is the .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=halMyGPhfVZGrdpibFIwEE0wZipP5lqu

DB_HOST=localhost *updated
DB_DATABASE=forge *updated
DB_USERNAME=forge *updated
DB_PASSWORD= *updated

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: You can't connect to the virtualbox from outside and neither the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following in your `.env` file or remove all the keys related to `DB` from `.env` file.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I had run into same issue, The problem is, the `database.php` file looks for the key `DB_DATABASE` etc. in the `.env` file. Since, that key is present in `.env` file, It doesn't consider the default value `forge` that you have provided in the statement `env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')`

In plain english, "Look for the key `DB_DATABASE` in `.env`, if present, use that else use `forge` as default"

In your case, the keys are present in `.env` file hence, though you provide `forge`, it considers `homestead` that is defined in the `.env` file. And hence the error Access denied on `'homestead'@'localhost'`

Hope I clarified the things.

Comment: hi thanks for your help.  I did what you suggested but I'm getting `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'   `

Comment: Which option did you try? 
Can you update your question with the contents of .env and database.php after making the change?

Comment: Tried it on my box. It is working and it should work for you too. You might be missing something

Comment: Your changes should work. Are you able to connect to the DB using mysql command? with username forge and password null?

Comment: after changing the .env file and database.php, don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: I'm getting ` Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock` when i type in mysql.

Comment: okay mysql works now.  But I'm getting access denied for user @localhost to database forge

Comment: @Sid  I think restart won't be required as we are making code level changes. 
@JackDuong Its unusual that you are getting an empty quote on the username. Generally, If you forget to give username, it automatically considers `root` user.

Comment: This is very frustrating.  Thanks for trying to help.